# Progress Bar in Nextjs 13 App Directories

Tags: next.js

i am using nextjs 13 app dir now i want to add progress bar when user navigate page i have no idea to do it . i have searched on google but it work  only for simple next js not working with app dir please help me

Help me how to implement it . thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router#router-events 

Answer (score 2):

I use `nextjs-toploader` with no problems.
Inside `app/layout.jsx` file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import NextTopLoader from 'nextjs-toploader';

export default function Layout({ children, user }) {
   ...
return (
<html id="pageRoot">
  <body className="...">
    <NextTopLoader />
    ...
  </body>
</html>
)}
```

Comment: yes it work with Link tage well. but when we use useRouter from next/navigation seem it is not